# Virtual Ubuntu 18.04 gets slow over time

Tags: virtualbox, 18.04, virtualization

I was happily running Ubuntu 16.04 as a virtual machine using Virtualbox on my Windows PC for about a year. Recently I decided to upgrade that (with do-release-upgrade) to 18.04.

The problem is that once I start using the VM, it gets slow over the time - really slow (**several seconds response time** for my keyboard and mouse inputs). Only rebooting the VM solves the issue temporarily. Slowing down typically starts after 30-60 minutes of uptime. Even right after booting up the VM it's not as quick and responsive as it used to be with 16.04, but it's still usable (lag is maybe 100-200 milliseconds.)

VM specs:

- My host has 16 gigs of DDR4, from which I have given 4 gigs for the VM.
- The VM has 2 cores to use of my i7 Skylake (with 100% execution gap).
- I have given the VM 128mb video memory from my 1070 GTX.
- 3D acceleration is enabled
- VTx and nested paging are enabled
- I have guest additions installed (v 5.2.16)
- On the VM I have installed additional drivers installed for graphics:

[image]

Any idea what additional tests I could do to identify the cause of this issue?

Comment: I would contact virtual box directly

Comment: Did you find the solution to this issue ? I am in a similar state!

Answer (score 0):

**[Note]:** Try this solution if you have used "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" option which is the automatic partitioning during installation:

**Solution:**

Reinstall Ubuntu, and instead of using the automatic partitioning, use manual partitioning by choosing "Something else" option on "Installation type" step.

[image: Screenshot]